# Returning a string representation of the number of albums and songs available

Tags: java, strings

What this method **should** do is return a `String` that displays how many albums and songs there are. This method is a `private` method of my `Artist` class which has a method called `albumCount()` and `songCount()`. The whole class probably needs an improvement but I will try that later. First I'd like this single method to be improved if possible.

```
public String toAlbumSongCount() {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    final int albumCount = albumCount();
    final int songCount = songCount();

    builder.append( albumCount );
    //Append albums instead of album if albumCount is greater than 1
    builder.append( (albumCount > 1) ? " albums" : " album" );
    builder.append( "," ); //Move this to the line above?
    builder.append( songCount );
    //Append songs instead of song if songCount is greater than 1
    builder.append( (songCount > 1 ) ? " songs" : " song" );

    return builder.toString();
}
```

I used the `StringBuilder` class because I heard a dozen of times that it will improve performance when concatenating Strings.
I wasn't sure about those two lines :

```
builder.append( (albumCount > 1) ? " albums" : " album" );
builder.append( (songCount > 1 ) ? " songs" : " song" );
```

Are they good enough with the comments above them?

I appreciate any help even if it means completely rewriting this method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think these are any major improvements, but there are many small things that I would change.

- `albumCount` and `songCount` is both the name of a variable, and of a method
- Pluralization can be extracted to a separate method
- Remove unnecessary comments and spaces

So here's what I would do:

```
public String toAlbumSongCount() {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    final int albumCount = getAlbumCount();
    final int songCount = getSongCount();

    builder.append(albumCount);
    builder.append(pluralize(albumCount, " album", " albums"));
    builder.append(", ");
    builder.append(songCount);
    builder.append(pluralize(songCount, " song", " songs"));

    return builder.toString();
}

private static final String pluralize(int count, String singular, String plural) {
    return count == 1 ? singular : plural;
}
```

A tiny extra thing that is often forgotten is to pass an argument to the `StringBuilder`, by default it is initialized with a capacity of 16 characters. If we look at a little example, `99 albums, 999 songs` we see that that's 20 characters. So the internal array in `AbstractStringBuilder` will need to be resized once. We could create the StringBuilder with a capacity of 24 to reduce the need for the resize.

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(24);
```

Comment: I like the way that pluralize can handle other types of plurals, like "mouse" and "mice". It will also be faster than the concatenation.

Comment: Your plurals are hardcoded which hinders localization. Of course, many times you don't need that. But if you do, there are languages for it is not enough to use a single plural. For example, in Czech, the plural form for 2 is different than the one for 5. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Czech_declension#Plural_forms

Comment: @user140547 This was not a question about localization. I never considered localization here. The issue that you raise can be easily fixed though, by for example using different pluralization methods for albums and songs, and read the appropriate strings from a localization file. Perhaps this might be something that you want to implement yourself? Could be an interesting follow-up to this question.

Comment: Many times you don't need localization, for sure, but it can also be kept in mind that sometimes you need it. Anyway, Java has already a solution for that kind of problems, as I mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 5):

Text manipulation like that is always a pain. I like to extract functions for things like this, though.

```
private static final String simplePlural (int count, String noun) {
    if (count == 1) {
        return "1 " + noun;
    }
    return count + " " + noun + "s";
}
```

With that function, your code becomes:

```
public String toAlbumSongCount() {
    return simplePlural(albumCount(), "album") 
       + ", " + simplePlural(songCount(), "song");
}
```

I know there's no StringBuilder in there, but the performance benefit for something that's seldom used, will be negligible, and this is more readable.

Note that the code above adds a space after the comma, which your code is missing.

Comment: and now localize it ;) Your code does not account for a different plural form than `s`

Comment: There is a StringBuilder there - it's implicit.  If you look at the byte code generated, you'll see the creation and destruction of StringBuilders. I would also point out that this code appears to create three StringBuilders (once for each simplePlural invocation, one for the overall), and two additional Strings (which are then left to collection).  Consider the object creation / collection when running simplePlural hundreds or thousands of times.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to keep the `StringBuilder`, you use its [fluent interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface#Java)
like this to remove some clutter.

```
    builder.append("first")
       .append("second")
       .toString();
```

BTW, there is also some support in Java for pluralization and so on, but I have to admit I have never used it because in most cases it is really simpler to use a simple if. But if you want the perfect, maybe a bit overengineered solution for internationalization, you can have a look at [ChoiceFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/choiceFormat.html)

Answer (score 1):

I would use Java's built-in message formatting method, [`MessageFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html). It has a means to select different text choices based on a number:

```
public String toAlbumSongCount() {      
    return MessageFormat.format(
        "{0,number} {0,choice,1#album|1<albums},{1,number} {1,choice,1#song|1<songs}",
        albumCount(), // parameter 0
        songCount()); // parameter 1
}
```